# Why does the variable in header file give an error?

Tags: c, variables, header-files

My Header file test.h contains two variables that are deined as:

```
 #ifndef TEST_H_
 #define TEST_H_

 #define APPS 6;
 #define NODES 1;

 #endif;
```

I use it another header file called test2.h as follows:

```
#include"test.h"
typedef struct {
       uint8 State[APPS];
} AppState;
```

But I get an error in the test.h file saying

```
expected ']' before ';' token
```

Since there are no brackets I have no idea why I get this strange error. Could somebody please point out my mistake.Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Do not define constants with `;` at the end:

```
#define APPS 6
#define NODES 1
```

Otherwise this line:

```
 uint8 State[APPS];
```

Become this:

```
 uint8 State[6;];
```

With is obviously not compilying. You may think about `#define` as a "search and replace".

Comment: That was the mistake!! :) Thank you!